# ASP.NET Web Form User Data - Not Stored in SQL

Tags: asp.net, webforms, advantage-database-server

I have an ASP.NET Web Form application (.NET 4.5), and my connection string is set to connect to my Advantage Database Server (ADS). I am trying to utilize the pre-canned forms already in the ASP.NET Web Forms page for user accounts, but I have a problem: I don't know where the data is being stored.

I know in a normal situation, this data would be stored in a localDB that is set up in the connection string in Web.config. However, as I mentioned, I am not using SQL, I am using ADS.

Anyone know where this data is getting stored, since it isn't creating a localDB .mdf file?

Comment: Did you try looking at the connection strings in your application? The default template uses ASP.NET Identity. Just look at what connection string is being passed to it and that will tell you where the data is.

Comment: Yes, my web.config connection string is set to my ADS database, but there is no data being stored there.

Comment: Just because you have a connection string in your web.config doesn't mean it's being used by ASP.NET Identity and Entity Framework. Look at the constructor for the context, see what connection string it's using.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find that?

Comment: In a web application created by VS with Individual user accounts, look at `Models/IdentityModels.cs`. See the constructor for `ApplicationDbContext`? It's passing `"DefaultConnection"` as the name of the connection string from web.config that it will use.

Comment: Yes, I have public ApplicationDbContext()
: base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)

Comment: Then the data will be stored wherever the `DefaultConnection` connection string in your `web.config` points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mason, I found the problem. The "Default Connection" of ApplicationDbContext should have been changed to match my web.config file.

I added a second connection string (since my first points to my ADS Database) and named it "UserAccounts." This has the same default path to a local SQL DB that Visual Studio generates by default when creating a Web Form application. So now I have my user account data being stored locally. I was, up to this point, unaware that you could add multiple connection strings to different databases.